# is this density $f(x;\theta) = (1/\theta) x^{\theta -1} $ an exponential family?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

does anyone have experience to answer, is this density function:

$$f(x;\theta) = (1/\theta) x^{\theta -1} $$  for $0<x<1$ and $\theta>0$

an exponential family?

and what is the kind of distribution for that function?

Comment: What is the domain of x? $[0,+\infty)$?

Comment: For sure it is a a particular case of a Beta distribution.

Comment: It should be $\theta x^{\theta-1}$ to be a valid density.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a $\mathrm{Beta}(\theta,1)$.

If $\theta$ is integer, you can think it is the density of the max of $\theta$ IID uniform $[0,1]$ rvs.

Sorry previous statement was wrong: also Wikipedia
"The exponential families include many of the most common distributions, including the normal, exponential, gamma, chi-squared, beta,"

You can write the pdf as:

$$ f(x;\theta) = \theta^{-1}\cdot \exp\left( (\theta-1)\log(x)\right) $$

Comment: does $Beta(\theta,1)$ can be said  as exponential family? which is we call exponentital family if it satisfy $Q(\theta)T(x)+D(\theta)+S(x)$

Comment: @valeria sorry did a mistake corrected now